# not able to ftp using ftp client but command line

Tags: ftp

I'm facing a problem which to ftp files using ftp client (Filezilla), since it always prompt me `Error: Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing`, but when I tried ftp using command line, it works fine form me.... does anyone have idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for this, its because command line using Active mode for ftp, but my ftp client using Passive mode, change it to Active mode will do :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use passive mode in your Filezilla client